# missing return statement Fibonnacci Java

Tags: java

```
public class FibonacciGenerator
{  
    //instance variables
    private int recent ; //one values ago
    private int previous ; //two values ago
    private int n ; // the number of values returned so far

    /**
       Constructs the generator by setting the instance variables to 1
    */
    public FibonacciGenerator()
    {   
        recent = 1 ;
        previous = 1 ;
        n = 0 ;
    }

    /**
       Produces the next Fibonacci number
       @return the next in the Fibonacci sequence
    */
    public int next()
    {  
        n ++ ;
        if (n == 1) return 1 ;
        if (n == 2) return 1 ;
        int result = recent + previous ;
        //----------------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 3
        // 1. Update previous and recent, and 2. return result.
        previous++;
        recent++;
        return result;
        //----------------------End here. Please do not remove this comment. Reminder: no changes outside the todo regions.
    }
}

import java.util.* ;

public class FibonacciGeneratorTester
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        System.out.println("The 1st Fibonacci number is: "
                   + getFibonacci(1)) ;
        System.out.println("The 10th Fibonacci number is: "
                   + getFibonacci(10)) ;
    }
    /**
       A static method to return the n'th Fibonacci number
       @param n the index of the Fibonacci number
       @return the n'th Fibonacci number
     */
    public static int getFibonacci(int n)
    {
        FibonacciGenerator generator = new FibonacciGenerator() ;
        int result = 0 ;
        //----------------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 4
        // 1. Write a for-loop that calls the generator n times 2  . return the last result of the call.
        for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
            generator.next();
            return result;
        }
    }
}
```

missing return statement second last curly brace highlighted. Is my for loop correct?.......................................................................................................................................................

Comment: Your `previous` and `recent` will always be the same since they both start at one and are both incremented by one always at the same time.  That already screws up your desired result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your for loop begins:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
```

If n was less than 1, it would immediately exit, and there is no return statement between the end of the loop and the end of the method.  That is the missing return statement.

Answer (score 1):

Look at this:

```
public static int getFibonacci(int n)
{
    FibonacciGenerator generator = new FibonacciGenerator() ;
    int result = 0 ;
    //----------------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 4
    // 1. Write a for-loop that calls the generator n times 2  . return the last result of the call.
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        generator.next();
        return result;
    }
}
```

It must return an int. Look closer at your loop. What is n = 0?
That's right it won't return anything. That is not allowed here.

Answer (score 1):

```
public static int getFibonacci(int n)
{
    FibonacciGenerator generator = new FibonacciGenerator() ;
    int result = 0 ;
    //----------------Start below here. To do: approximate lines of code = 4
    // 1. Write a for-loop that calls the generator n times 2  . return the last result of the call.
    for (int i = 1; i <= n; i++){
        generator.next();
    }
return result;
//put a return statement here, instead of in your loop. 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS  CODE:

```
import java.util.*;   
public class Fibonnacci{
 public static void main(String args[]){
  int num;
  Scanner in=new Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.println("Enter an integer");
  num = in.nextInt();
  System.out.println("Fibonacci Series");
  int sum=0,a=0,b=1;
  for(int i=0;i<num;i++){
   System.out.print(" "+sum);
   a = b;
   b = sum;
   sum = a + b;
  }
 }
}
```